# How can we evaluate the ratio of abundance of Carbon to Li, Be and B?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, stars

In stars' nuclear processes, if the triple $\alpha$ reaction explain why Carbon is much more abundant than Li, Be, B, how can we evaluate the ration of abundance to ~$10^5$ times ? Is it possible to give an approximate theoretical evaluation of it with the binding energy and/or the coulomb barrier of these elements ?

All the stuff I have to answer this question is [here](http://agiamman.web.cern.ch/agiamman/astro/astro3.pdf) (question in slide 16), perhaps also with the help of the  H. A. Bethe's paper : [Energy Production in Stars](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.55.434).

I know how to explain qualitatively why Carbon is much more abundant than Li, Be and B. I can also say that experimentally we observe a ratio of ~$10^5$ between C and Li, Be, B. But I don't see how we can deduce this ratio theoretically.

A plot which show the abundance of the elements in the solar system :

[image]

Comment: We observe Li, Be & B in space (using, e.g., [AMS-02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Magnetic_Spectrometer)), so it's not clear what you mean by "evaulating the ration of abundance".

Comment: I want to know if there is a theoretical manner to deduce the ratio that fit the experimental data.

Comment: My instinct is that it comes from the [nuclear binding energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Nuclear_binding_energy_curve), if you look at the graph the average binding energy per nucleon is higher for He than Li, Be or B but C just about tops it. So they're more stable sitting at Helium or Carbon. Considering these compared to your rates of production may give the answer.

Comment: The fusion rate of the [triple $\alpha$ reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-alpha_process) is in $T^{40}$. The difference in binding energy between C and Li,Be or B is ~30Mev. I don't see how we arrive at  ~$10^5$ times for the ratio of abundance.

Comment: What is your plot of? What account have you taken of the destruction and creation mechanisms of these elements, or their primordial abundances? What research *have* you done?

Comment: The plot : abundance of elements in the sun. The $^{12}\rm C$ is not destroyed because catalyst in CNO cycle. Creation mechanism for $^{12}\rm C$ : [triple α reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-alpha_process) before being in the sun. I have read this article
 [Abundances of the Elements](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/RevModPhys.28.53) which deals with the experimental data and this article [Theory of the Origin and Relative Abundance Distribution of the Elements](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.22.153) which deals with theory on the abundance of the elements.

Comment: But the second article was a little bit obscure for me.

Comment: Where did you get this plot from? The abundance by number of Li is nearly 11 orders of magnitude less than hydrogen in the Sun. It looks more like 8 orders of magnitude less on your plot. Are you sure this isn't a deduction of the solar system abundances based on meteorites (where the Li abundance is much higher than in the Sun)?

Comment: Right, it's the plot of the solar system abundance. But still my question remain. In the slides, nothing is precise to calculate this ratio. I thought it was a simple ratio to find with binding energy, heigh of coulomb barrier, fusion T°...